# Is there a way I can modify some lines in site html code so it marks the checkbox?

Tags: python, html, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup

So, there's a site I'm trying to parse so it can automatically raising my offers every two hours.
The site designed in that way that you have to mark with checkboxes the lots you want to raise.
Somehow in html code the checkbox doesn't have value, instead it looks like this:

I have to click it manually via using

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "idk what to write so it checks it"))).click()
```

But I really don't know how do I find it so it can be clicked.

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="613" checked=""> 
  # value - lot id, checked - means the checkbox is marked
<label>
  # and non-checked checkbox code looks like this:

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="613">
<label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `By.CLASS_NAME` here since it has no `class`.
You *can* use:

---

- [`By.CSS_SELECTOR`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) to find by [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

```py
chbVal = '613' # in case you need be able to change this

(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'label > input[type="checkbox"][value="{chbVal}"][checked=""]') # for checked

(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'label > input[type="checkbox"][value="{chbVal}"]:not([checked])') # for unchecked
```

---

- or [`By.XPATH`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) to find by [Xpath](https://devhints.io/xpath)

```py
chbVal = '613' # in case you need be able to change this

(By.XPATH, f'//label/input[@type="checkbox"][@value="{chbVal}"][@checked=""]') # for checked

(By.XPATH, f'//label/input[@type="checkbox"][@value="{chbVal}"][not(@checked="")]') # for unchecked
```

---

**Note:** These are just based on the html snippet you've included - there might by parent elements with better identifiers that you need to include in your path/selector.

---

Also,

> Somehow in html code the checkbox doesn't have value

but [in your snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDOGx.png) it *does* have `value`...? Anyway, the examples above include `value`, but you don't have to include them; you can even *exclude* them with `not(...)` as shown for `checked`. (Btw, `not(checked)`/`not(@checked)` should exclude elements that have a `checked` attribute at all, no matter what the value is.)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly ^^
I didn't even thought about using By.CSS_SELECTOR, now I'm gonna try it in some more tasks :p

Comment: @wasdy glad it helped! [yeah, it's super useful - I love css selectors]